# Babel, Unexpected token (15:33) ::

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am experimenting with cycle-blessed, with the  example js code provided on its GitHub page, but am experiencing issues.

```
import { run } from '@cycle/core';
import blessed from 'blessed';
import { makeTermDriver, box } from 'cycle-blessed';
import { Observable as $ } from 'rx';

let screen = blessed.screen({ smartCSR: true, useBCE: true, title:    
'Hello, World!' });
let BlueBox = text => box({ border: { type: 'line', fg: 'blue' } },
text);         

run(({ term }) => ({
term: $.just(BlueBox('Hello, World!')),
exit: term.on('key C-c')
}), {
term: makeTermDriver(screen),
exit: exit$ => exit$.forEach(::process.exit)
});
```

I believe that this code can be ran with Babel, but trying to run:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dest
```

results in:

```
13 | }), {
14 |     term: makeTermDriver(screen),
15 |     exit: exit$ => exit$.forEach(::process.exit)
   |                                  ^
16 | });
```

Am I correct in thinking babel can be used to transpile this code?

Any help appreciated.

.babelrc:

```
{
"presets": ["es2015"]
}
{
"plugins": ["transform-function-bind"]

}
```

Comment: ::process.exit is a function which receives as a parameter an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::` is an experimental function syntax which performs function binding and method extraction.

To transpile the code using this operator it you need to install and add a [transform-function-bind](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/) plugin to your .babelrc file.

First install it from npm:

```
$ npm install babel-plugin-transform-function-bind
```

Then change your .babelrc file to this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-function-bind"]
}
```

Comment: "presets": ["es2015"] in .babelrc causes a JSON syntax error.
 
I assume I am writing the file incorrectly.

Comment: No it doesn't. It's perfectly valid JSON. You probably forgot a comma. Show your entire file.

Comment: Do you happen to know what causes "No active screen error" after trying to run transpiled code? the same code from the github page